# Database mapping in Leaflet with (JSON, AJAX)

Tags: json, ajax, database, laravel, leaflet

I get this JSON from DeviceNewController

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $device_new = Device_new::with(['device']);

    return Device_new::all()->toJson();
}
```

And when I wrote AJAX in view blade, it show me data from DB in console.

```
<script>
    var newdev = new XMLHttpRequest();
    newdev.open('GET', '/devices_new');
    newdev.onload = function() {
        console.log(newdev.responseText);
    };
    newdev.send();
</script>
```

But I need to pass it in Leaflet script and write all data on map (coordinates, markers, device info)

When I set all in one script, there is no data in console, I can not fix it.

```
var newdev = new XMLHttpRequest();
    newdev.open('GET', '/devices_new');
    newdev.onload = function() {
        var coordinates = newdev.responseText;

    for (var i=0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        if(coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y){
        var marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
        .bindPopup("Device: "+coordinates[i].device_type+'<br>' + "Time: "+coordinates[i].datetime)

        .addTo(map);
        }
    };
    };
    newdev.send();
```

Did i make a mistake somewhere, is this correct???

Answer (score 0):

You miss understood Ajax. Ajax is a function from JQuery, a JS library.

> The ajax() method is used to perform an AJAX (asynchronous HTTP) request.

You have to add the JQuery library to your source, then you can create a Ajax call.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

```
$.ajax({url: "/devices_new", success: function(result){
     //result = JSON.parse(result); // If your result is not a json Object.
     var coordinates = result;

    for (var i=0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        if(coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y){
        var marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
        .bindPopup("Device: "+coordinates[i].device_type+'<br>' + "Time: "+coordinates[i].datetime)

        .addTo(map);
        }
    }
  },
   error: function(xhr){
      alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }});

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to temporarily show "result" in blade from that function? And in same time to send data to map?

Comment: `console.log(result)`. What do you mean with "same time"? after the data get from "devices_new" the function `success` is called. Then you can do with that data what you want. Your data are not gone if you print them out in the console.

Comment: `document.getElmentById('divid').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);`

Answer (score 0):

I make it on this way, and its working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            /* the route pointing to the post function */
            url: '/device_new',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                message: $(".getinfo").val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
            success: function(data) {
                var coordinates = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
                        var marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                            .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)

                            .addTo(map);
                    }
                }

                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```